# Failure tolerance counter workaround/alternatives

Tags: monit

I use monit to monitor my daemon with the HTTP API and restart it if needed. In addition to just checking that the process is not dead, I also added an HTTP check (`if failed port 80 protocol http request "/api/status"`) with a failure tolerance counter (`for N cycles`). I use the counter to avoid restarting the daemon in case of singular failed requests (e.g. due to high load). The problem is, that the failures counter seems not to reset after the daemon is successfully restarted. I.e., consider the following scenario:

1. Monit and the daemon are started.
2. The daemon is locked (e.g. due to a software bug) and stops responding to the HTTP requests.
3. Monit waits for N consecutive HTTP request failures and restarts the daemon.
4. The first monit HTTP request after the daemon restart fails again (e.g., because the daemon needs some time to get online and start serving requests).
5. Monit restarts the daemon again. Go to item 4.

This seems to be a bug and actually there is an issue [64](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/64) (fixed) and [787](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/787/fail-counter-does-not-reset-after-program) (open). Since the second issue is opened for a year already, I do not have much hope of it to be fixed soon, so I would like to know is there a good workaround for this case.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what I needed, I ended up with the following alternative:

1. Use large enough value for the `timeout` parameter of the `start program` token, to give the server enough to get online. The connection tests are not performed by monit during this time.
2. Use the `retry` parameter in the `if failed port` clause to tolerate singular failures. Unfortunately, the retries are done immediately (after request failure or `timeout`), not in the next poll cycle.
3. Use `for N cycles` parameter, to improve failure tolerance at least partially.

Basically, I have the following monitrc structure:

```
set daemon 5
check process server ...
   start program = "..." with timeout 60 seconds
   stop program = "..."
   if failed port 80 protocol http request "/status" with retry 10 and timeout 5 seconds for 5 cycles then restart
```